# This view is not constrained, it only has designtime positions, so it will jump to (0,0) unless you add constraints The

Tags: android-layout, constraints

This view is not constrained, it only has designtime positions, so it will jump to (0,0) unless you add constraints.

[image]

The layout editor allows you to place widgets anywhere on the canvas, and it records the current position with designtime attributes (such as layout_editor_absoluteX.) These attributes are not applied at runtime, so if you push your layout on a device, the widgets may appear in a different location than shown in the editor. To fix this, make sure a widget has both horizontal and vertical constraints by dragging from the edge connections.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 60):

This may help someone.
I am using Android Studio 3.1 and i faced same problem but i didn't find these options (Constraint Layout -> Infer Layout) as suggested in the above answer.
Then after carefully checking i found "Infer Constraint" option above the layout window (refer to screenshot below in step 1)

Step 1: Click on "Infer Constraint". This may solve your problem, but if your widget still not visible (as in my case), then follow step 2.
[image]

Step 2: Click on "AppTheme" and select "NoTitleBar" theme as selected in the screenshot
[image]

This solved my problem.

Comment: thanks,  the second option  solved my problem too. my version is 3.1.3

Answer (score 13):

Add the following piece of code to your code:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

Comment: I was getting this warning but the output was okay without any scroll as expected. What should i change here to get the scroll . With your 4 lines the view is coming as cropped. not all lines neither the scroll view. Please suggest what changes should I make here. Thanks <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#3d455b">

  ...
    </ScrollView>

Answer (score 6):

Right click on design layout in Android Studio, then select "Constrain Layout" and sub menu is open, then select "infer Layout" and compile your App.

Comment: The "Constrain Layout" option does not appear in Android Studio 3.1. What to do now?

Answer (score 5):

From Android Studio v3 and up, Infer Constraint was removed from the dropdown.

Use the magic wand icon in the toolbar menu above the design preview; there is the "Infer Constraints" button. Click on this button, this will automatically add some lines in the text field and the red line will be removed.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/77dfo.png]

Answer (score 2):

In my project this error was caused by `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` and `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` expressions. `fill_parent` constant is obsolete. Changing to to `match_parent` solved the problem:

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

</ViewFlipper>
```

Answer (score 1):

Android studio hint says:

This view is not constrained. It only has designtime positions, so it will jump to (0,0) at runtime unless you add the constraints less... (Ctrl+F1) 
The layout editor allows you to place widgets anywhere on the canvas, and it records the current position with designtime attributes (such as layout_editor_absoluteX). These attributes are not applied at runtime, so if you push your layout on a device, the widgets may appear in a different location than shown in the editor.

**To fix this, make sure a widget has both horizontal and vertical constraints by dragging from the edge connections.**

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Good Work. Just make a little change, according to my experience, You have to CLICK the " Infer Constraint " (a magic stick button).To make Infer Constraint appear, Remember the Palette (button/image/text etc) which you dragged on the constraint layout (screen). You have to click the very palette and it'll appear on the top right side. Click that magic stick button and your error will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my fix (100% working):

1, Please drag and drop the images that you entered in folder "drawable". Note to keep the original name

2, Click the **play(Green Triangle)** button

3, It shows an error please click on your image and right click> **Refactor**> **Rename**>
**All place**> **Refactor** and then run the application again> **Restart**

**Note that the image name must not contain "-", "_"**

When you run the app it will save the name to memory so just re-enter the image with your original name and then click **Refactor> Rename>** enter another name (must not contain any characters)> select **All place**(This will change the entire corrupted name to something that works better)> Refactor and rerun your application!

Answer (score 0):

To position a **SurfaceView** in the center of the **ConstraintLayout**, using the holder setFixedSize, change layout_width to "wrap_content".

```
// setting holder
holder?.setFixedSize(640, 480)
```

**XML**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id = "@+id/player_view"
    android:gravity = "center"
    android:layout_width = "0dp"
    android:layout_height = "0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf = "parent"
    app: layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf = "parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf = "parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf = "parent">

        <SurfaceView
            android:id = "@+id/surfaceView"
            android:gravity = "center"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf = "parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf = "parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf = "parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf = "parent"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```